# How do I use supervisord's environment option in program sections?

Tags: supervisord

The [supervisord documentation](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html) states that

> No shell is executed by supervisord when it runs a subprocess, so
>   environment variables such as USER, PATH, HOME, SHELL, LOGNAME, etc.
>   are not changed from their defaults or otherwise reassigned. (...)
>   If you need to set environment variables for a
>   particular program that might otherwise be set by a shell invocation
>   for a particular user, you must do it explicitly within the
>   environment= program config option.

The include an example, which I reproduced into `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/apache2.conf`:

```
[program:apache2]
command=/home/chrism/bin/httpd -c "ErrorLog /dev/stdout" -DFOREGROUND
user=chrism
environment=HOME=/home/chrism,USER=chrism
```

However,

```
# supervisorctl reread
ERROR: CANT_REREAD: Unexpected end of key/value pairs
```

Removing the 'environment' line of the apache2 configuration results in no parse errors for the re-read. What's dotty here? I'm using supervisor 3.0a8-1 on Debian Squeeze and note that the mainline supervisor is 3.0a10; I cannot find reference of `environment` has having been added since 3.0a8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings

says "Values containing non-alphanumeric characters should be placed in quotes"